# I need to make a structure repeat for each user using the bot. (mongoose, discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, discord, bots

I'm using MongoDB (mongoose) to create a database, which saves user notes, for my discord bot, which is being programmed in Discord.JS.

My "Guild.js" file:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
const Guild = Schema({
    id: String,

    user1: {
        note: {
            default: 'No notes here.',
            type: String
        }    
    }
})

module.exports = model('Guild', Guild)
```

I need the structure of "user1" to be repeated for each user using the bot. Something like this:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
const Guild = Schema({
    id: String,

    user1: {
        note: {
            default: 'No notes here.',
            type: String
        }    
    }

    user2: {
        note: {
            default: 'No notes here.',
            type: String
        }    
    }

    user3: {
        note: {
            default: 'No notes here.',
            type: String
        }    
    }
})

module.exports = model('Guild', Guild)
```

PS: The "user1", "user2", will be the user ids, so that I can compare with the user id that typed the command ".push-note" and send the correct note.

I hope that I have provided all the necessary information correctly. I'm sorry if there are any English errors, I'm Brazilian.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use array of users

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const User = Schema({
   id: String,
   note:{
      default: 'No notes here.',
      type: String
   }
})

const Guild = Schema({
   id: String,
   users:[User]
})

module.exports = model('Guild', Guild)
```

and the compare user id from array
//I didn't try to run in node, could be some typos there